# showing previous slide with using show/hide code

Tags: slider, hide, show

I have simple manual text slider with using show/hide code. every thing is ok but when i click previous slide button, current text will be hide but previous one won't show. why it doesn't show ?!

this is my html code:

```
<div class="hand_1" id="hand_1">
    <img id="hand_img_1" src="myimage1.png" width="176.25" height="332.25" />
    <div class="hand_text_1">
        <h2>header</h2>
        <p>paragraph 1</p>
            <div class="connect-links">
                <a id="next_icon_1" href="#" ></a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="hand_2" id="hand_2" style="display:none;">
    <img id="hand_img_2" src="myimage2.png" width="176.25" height="332.25" />
    <div class="hand_text_2">
        <h2>header 2</h2>
        <p>paragraph 2</p>
            <div class="connect-links">
                <a id="next_icon_2" href="#"></a>
                <a id="previous_icon_2" href="#"></a>
            </div>                              
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                            $('#next_icon_1').on("click", function(){
                            $('#hand_img_1').fadeOut('fast');
                            $('.hand_text_1').fadeOut('fast');
                            $('.hand_2').fadeIn('fast');
                                });                             
                            $('#previous_icon_2').on("click", function(){
                            $('#hand_img_2').fadeOut('fast');
                            $('.hand_text_2').fadeOut('fast');
                            $('.hand_1').fadeIn('fast');
                            });                             
                        });
```

Comment: there is no one to help ?! :(

Comment: one month left but nobody can answer my question !!!!

Comment: I really neeed help :(